# Javascript and jQuery code doesn't execute using Flask/Jinja2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flask, jinja2

I've recently completed the Flask tutorial, and after having thouroughly searched for an answer for this - I decided to ask for help myself:
When I try to add a jQuery code to the HTML file, it doesn't execute.
The code is the initialization of Materialize's select:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('select').material_select(); });
```

It worked before I started using Flask with this HTML file, and now it doesn't - the select dropdown isn't visible. Also, another Javascript that I added doesn't execute, including a simple "alert" function. Maybe I didn't add the script correctly?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery-3.1.1.min.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='materialize.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Even tried using `{% block javascript %}` that I saw in someone's answer, and the same result persisted.

Thank you all for your assistance!

Comment: Can you please link us to a jsfiddle? Or at least provide the code via an edit?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3th323pp/1/    This is basically it

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40561528/edit) your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).